# $_SESSION superglobal is being emptied unexpectedly

Tags: php, session

I am using sessions in an attempt to implement persistent logins for my users in a web application.  The back-end is php 7.2 and apache, provided through Namecheap shared hosting.

I am setting a session cookie on the client with a "cookie_lifetime" and "gc_maxlifetime" of 604,800 seconds (one week).  The server calls `session_start()` with these parameters and checks a `$_SESSION` key called "user_id" to see if the `session_start()` call has started an existing session (if the key is defined, the user is "logged in").  It does this every time the page is loaded.  Everything works fine until about 40 minutes of inactivity have gone by, then the next page refresh and attempt to call `session_start()` and access any `$_SESSION` keys returns undefined for everything, despite the session cookie still showing an "Expires" value several days in the future in DevTools.

My understanding was that "cookie_lifetime", "gc_maxlifetime", and the associated "Expires" header for setting the client-side cookie would preserve session information for at least as long as the time specified, but this interaction is demonstrating that regardless of what I put in those fields, the `$_SESSION` superglobal will not return anything meaningful beyond ~40 minutes of inactivity.

Am I not understanding this correctly, or is there perhaps something wrong from a server configuration standpoint that is beyond the scope of the client-server application code?

Comment: Apache may be clearing files from the tmp storage folder if they've been inactive for a certain amount of time, this would be set by the server controllers.

Comment: @Martin, my session files were *never* appearing there, though, even when checking a few seconds after creating a new session.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully get to the bottom of why this was occurring.  I did reach out to the Namecheap support staff, however, and they told me their sessions were not malfunctioning in the same way after ~40 minutes; they continued to see session values that had been set several hours previously when they tried to recreate the issue using the same code and configuration as I was using.

I dug into the server configuration and reviewed the output of a `phpinfo()` dump and determined that the `Registered save handlers` were set to `files user`.  I can't find out what the `user` component of that reflects, and maybe that's where the issue lies, but I *was* able to resolve the issue by explicitly specifying the `session.save_path` parameter rather than relying on the default (which was `no value` in the phpinfo output).

The support staff had said that the default location was `/home/[user]/tmp/` and their sessions were showing up there, but mine were not.  After adding the explicit `save_path` to php.ini, my sessions began to appear there and the ~40 minute expiration stopped occurring.

I'll hold off on accepting this as the answer in case anyone else can provide more insight/understanding, but I wanted to at least chime in saying that I had found a solution to my problem.  I'm not sure what was happening before, but I could not find my session files anywhere sensible in the directories of my shared host user account and I'm wondering if they were there at all.  It's also very strange to me that it worked for the support staff but not for me or a friend that I had test it on his own computer.

Comment: I have just seen this question and my first thoguht was to check the session file on the server. Explicitly setting a session path and other session values is always a good idea for an account as sharing session space is unwise on a shared environment.

Comment: Does `phpinfo` on the account show all the expected / correct session information?

Comment: @Martin, ```phpinfo``` did show all of the expected and correct session information for the other parameters I was setting (604800 for gc_maxlifetime and cookie_lifetime).